# Shani dev darshan from front

Tags: shani, darshan

Many people fear taking the Shani maharaj Darshan from front side , they avoid looking into the eyes of idol of Shani. Is there any shastra reference for the same. Thank you for your inputs. Pranam.

Comment: Maybe to avoid the 'Drishti'.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe people avoid 'Drushti' (vision) of Shani Deva. This are some verses from Shani Mahatmya:

> त्याची द्दष्टी पडे जयावर ॥ करी तयाचा चकनाचूर ॥ अथवा कृपा करी जयावर ॥ तयासी सर्व आनंदच प्राप्त होय ॥५८॥

On whome his eyesight falls, he shatters him. For whome he shows his sympathy, he gains all sorts of Happiness.

> द्दष्टीचा ऐका चमत्कार ॥ जन्मला जेव्हा शनैश्चर ॥ तेव्हा द्दष्टी पडली पित्यावर ॥ तेणें कुष्ठ भरला सर्वांगी ॥५९॥

Now listen! A miracle of his Drushti, when Shani took birth his Drusti falled on his father, and then he suffered from 'Kushta-rog' (a type of disease)

> पित्याच्या रथीं होता जो सारथी ॥ तो पांगुळ झाला निश्चिती ॥ अश्वचिता नेत्रांप्रती ॥ अंधत्व आले तत्क्षणी ॥६०॥

The charioteer became paralyzed, and the horses became blind.

> तेव्हा त्यांनी उपाय केले फार ॥ तरी गूण न येचि अणुमात्र ॥ जव द्दष्टी फिरवी शनैश्चर ॥ तंव निघेही आरोग्य हाले ॥६१॥

They performed numerous methods to cure them, but there was no change. Then, when Shani deva turned his Drushti away they all got recoverd!

Comment: Yes makes sense. Thank you for sharing, pranam